# JSON for mobile

Tags: php, json, mobile

I have script for video player

```
<?php
$id = 35719350987;
$url = 'http://ok.ru/dk?cmd=videoPlayerMetadata&mid='.$id;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'viewport=1040; _flashVersion=1');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Accept: *'));   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'ok.ru/videoembed/'.$id);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $html = curl_exec($ch); 
    $json = json_decode($html);
?>
```

The output of browser chrome is

> callbackFunc([ {file:"........"video/mp4"}])

Is work 
But when i use mobile is not work 
When from mobile json need to take `[{"name":"mobile","url":"....}` , from 
http://www.ok.ru/dk?cmd=videoPlayerMetadata&mid=35719350987 but is not take nothing

Comment: PHP is executed on the server, not in the browser, so your PHP is not relevant to the problem if the problem is only on mobile. You need to post whatever JavaScript you're using on mobile that is causing the problem.

Comment: Besides, this is JSONP, not JSON and was meant to be called from JavaScript/AJAX, not from PHP/cURL.

Comment: i think that the problem is curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

Comment: if you read any of the comments above yours, you would know that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This line does not work curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); instead curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.3  Mobile');  but it does not work in mobile browsers